# mvn release:perform fails in java 8 - added javadoc plugin

Tags: java, maven, java-8, javadoc, release

I'm having trouble running release:perform with Java 8 and maven 3.0.5. I get an error when the Javadoc is generated. I have added the javadoc plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
               <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The strange thing is that it works fine when I run 'mvn javadoc:javadoc' or 'mvn javadoc:jar'. Does anyone have a fix for this?

I'm getting this error after everything is generated:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3:jar (attach-javadocs) on project sdm: MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc:
[INFO] [ERROR] C:\dir...\JavaClass.java:50: error: self-closing element not allowed
[INFO] [ERROR] * <p/>
[INFO] [ERROR] ^
[INFO] [ERROR]
[INFO] [ERROR] Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @packages
[INFO] [ERROR]
[INFO] [ERROR] Refer to the generated Javadoc files in 'C:\dir.....\' dir.
```

Comment: Please provide the exact error message.

Comment: Please provide the complete error message, also with the log output what happened directly before the error, if possible.

Comment: It generates everything (just as when I run mvn javadoc:javadoc), but then the 'Failed to execute...' comes followed by a ton of errors that's similar to the first error (self closing element not allowed). Then the 'Command line was...' appears.

Comment: Just an idea: try moving the `<configuration>` on the same level as the `<executions>` instead of making it specific to a single execution.

Comment: Well, I would go through the source code and replace all occurences of `<p/>` with `<p>`. With an IDE or dedicated tool that takes a few seconds…

Comment: I agree with @DidierL's idea. Don't make the configuration execution-specific. This is probably the issue here.

Answer (score 4):

Try disabling doc linting completely for java 8:

```
<profile>
    <id>disable-javadoc-doclint</id>
    <activation>
        <jdk>[1.8,)</jdk>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Found it here: https://issues.shibboleth.net/jira/browse/JPAR-73

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately; I cannot tell you with the provided information why "-Xdoclint:none" isn't respected by the release plugin.

But a "simple" fix might just be to remove the argument altogether and actually fix the Javadoc issues the compiler reports (such as the self-closing elements which are not allowed).

Comment: For having migrated a big project to java 8 a few month ago, I can tell you that this would be no "simple" fix ;-)